# How can I get my text to be two lines with padding and ellipsis?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm having issues getting my text to be on two lines with ellipsis. I am able to get my ellipsis working but modifying `line-height` and `height` do nothing to change how many lines of text are shown. Any help on why I'm unable to change the number of lines would be great.

https://codepen.io/Joe_Scotto/pen/gjXoJy

Comment: just remove this `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: @fayeed Okay, that seems to get it to multiple lines which I have been able to do but the issue now is that I'm unable to have proper padding, text is hanging out off the box. It alsos removes the ellipsis

Comment: don't set the height it will automatically adjust

Comment: If I don't set the height, how am I able to limit it to just two lines?

Comment: can you use `span` tag for content inside `h6` tag

Comment: Check this https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/xJPYxW

Comment: @JoeScotta Check this [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBOQRa#anon-login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

CSS

```
.slick-slide {
  border-radius: 7px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;

  img {
    bottom: 0;        
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .info {
    background: rgba(black, 0.5);
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    h6 {
      display: -webkit-box;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;            
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;            
    }
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/kieran/pen/RBjQgX)

All you need to do is adjust the `-webkit-line-clamp` value to however many lines you want visible.

Comment: That's working pretty good except when resizing it doesn't always add it properly, sometimes overflow is visible.

Comment: I should mention, I'm using this inside of a slick.js slider.

Answer (score 0):

I updated you code using the `-webkit-line-clamp: 2` property.Check the browser support [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp) and [here](https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/xJPYxW) is the codepen

```css
.slick-slide {
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.slick-slide img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.slick-slide .info {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.slick-slide .info h6 {
  border: 1.5px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: block-axis;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick-slide">
    <div class="info">
        <h6>elements that are on fire my dude elements that are on fire my dude elements that are on fire my dude elements that are on fire my dude</h6>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

Comment: Overflow is still visible on the bottom though, is there no way to get rid of that?

Comment: Overflow is still visible on the bottom though : i don't understand. Could you please  tell in detail

Comment: If you look at the code that's being run, you can see text right above the border.

Comment: That you can fix by adjusting the `height` or `line-height`, Can you try and let me know

Comment: Am trying that but with my design I'm going for I have to condense the text too much. Isn't there a way to just get rid of that text there? I thought that was the purpose of ellipsis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176959/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-joe-scotto).

Comment: @JoeScotto i believe this is the way to get rid of that..if you have 4 lines and you want to show ellipses in second line, still the 3rd and 4th line will be there which we have to cover up using overflow hidden

Comment: @JoeScotto did my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to [trim all lines with clip-path](https://codepen.io/truerenton/pen/RwGRyeq), that are still visible after '...'.

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 calc(100% - 20px), 100% calc(100% - 20px), 100% 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a perfect way.

**Use transparent border with same size replace of padding.**

```
// before
display: -webkit-box;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
padding: 24px;

// after
display: -webkit-box;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
border: 24px solid transparent;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.slick-slide .info {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.slick-slide .info h6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    height: 19px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
}
```

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens put both css class property with your old css property.